# Web Api Odata action methods using Get verb return 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to expose a document stream as an Action Method on a specific type. It would look something like this:

/odata/MyType(123)/stream <-- this returns a binary stream of data.

When accessing the above endpoint using GET I only get a 404, even though the endpoint is exposed as [HttpGet] on the Controller.

Sematically it would make sense to access this resource using the Get verb, as this is simply an operation for retrieval of data, and not side-effecting.

So far I've only gotten this to work by exposing the action method under the POST-verb.

The action method controller implementation currently look like this:

```
[HttpPost] // <-- I want this to be [HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Test([FromODataUri] int key, ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
    var fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"c:\somefile");

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StreamContent(fileStream)
        };
}
```

The code for registering the action method on 'MyType'

```
var entityTypeConfiguration = mapper.Builder.Entity<MyType>();
var actionConfiguration = entityTypeConfiguration.Action("stream");
actionConfiguration.Returns<HttpResponseMessage>();
```

The implementation is inspired by this article: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-actions

Anyone know how I can possible expose this action method as a Get?

Comment: What error do you get when you change the attribute to `[HttpGet]`?

Comment: Per the OData spec, actions must be invoked with POST, because they can have side effects. http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/odata-core/#10413_Invoking_an_Action

Comment: Prescott: I get a 404. Updated my question.

Comment: Mike Wasson: I believe that is the answer yes... Why don't you just post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OData has better semantics for exposing streams for an entity. You can either use named streams or Media Link Entry (MLE). Read about it [here](http://www.odata.org/2010/10/enhancing-odata-support-for-streams/) and [here](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/document.php?document_id=50116).

Named streams seem to suit your scenario better. I have a sample [here](https://gist.github.com/raghuramn/6237208) that shows how to use extensibility points in web API OData to do named streams.

Answer (score 3):

Question is old, but I have been struggling with this and the solution I found in my case may be useful for others: define the "Action" GET as a "Function" instead of an "Action".

In the scenario presented in the question, this would be:

```
var actionConfiguration = entityTypeConfiguration.Function("stream");
```

This is recommended in [the documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions): "The difference between actions and functions is that actions can have side effects, and functions do not. Both actions and functions can return data."